# 2 y-axis graph with x-axis as date and time . x value and y value data not showing on mouse point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I created 2 y-axises (`y, y1`) graph with x-axis as date and time. While I am pointing the graph `y` and `x` its showing me data of `x` and `y1`. Here is the code with proof:

```
import sqlite3,time,datetime,os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

def bytedate2num(fmt):
    def converter(b):
        return mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)(b.decode('ascii'))
    return converter
conn = sqlite3.connect("Datas.db")
c = conn.cursor()
sql= "SELECT timestap,date,val,num FROM table"
graphArray = []
temp=0
for row in c.execute(sql):
    if temp > int(row[0]):
        continue
    else:
        temp=int(row[0])
    graphArray.append(row[1]+','+row[2]+','+row[3])

date_converter = bytedate2num("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
date_Formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d %H:%M')
datestime, val, num= np.loadtxt(graphArray,delimiter=',', unpack=True,converters={ 0: date_converter})
fig = plt.figure()
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
fig_size[0] = 15
fig_size[1] = 12
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot_date(datestime, val, 'g-')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_Formatter)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('g')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot_date(datestime, num, 'r-')
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

> Sample Data
>
> timestamp  date    num val
>
> 1461685551626  2016-04-26 15:45:51 20.884  5
>
> 1461685572550  2016-04-26 15:46:12 1.009   5
>
> 1461685573560  2016-04-26 15:46:13 0.09    5
>
> 1461685551140  2016-04-26 15:45:51 22.24   5
>
> 1461685578914  2016-04-26 15:46:18 1.061   7
>
> 1461685573914  2016-04-26 15:46:13 1.061   7
>
> 1461685560734  2016-04-26 15:46:00 20.849  7
>
> 1461685581587  2016-04-26 15:46:21 0.736   7
>
> 1461685582334  2016-04-26 15:46:22 0.058   7
>
> 1461685582393  2016-04-26 15:46:22 0.057   7

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here.  You need to make a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can give you the best help.  In particular, we can't replicate your `sqlite` database, so please ensure you put in some sample data.  Good luck!

Comment: Helo I have added sample data. Once review